# Simple ComboBox Issue on Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, combobox, settings

Is there way in Delphi 6 to change the settings of a ComboBox so the user can't fill a custom text in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you set the `Style` property to `csDropDownList`.